# Flink Kafka Connector runtime error

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink

I am using:

- flink 1.1.2
- Kafka 2.10-0.10.0.1
- flink-connector-kafka-0.9.2.10-1.0.0

I am using the following very simple/basic app

```
Properties properties = new Properties();                               
properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:33334");         

properties.setProperty("partition.assignment.strategy", "org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor");
properties.setProperty("group.id", "test");                             
String topic = "mytopic";                                                

FlinkKafkaConsumer09<String> fkc =                                      
    new FlinkKafkaConsumer09<String>(topic, new SimpleStringSchema(), properties);

DataStream<String> stream = env.addSource(fkc);    
env.execute()
```

After compiling it using maven and when I try to run using the following command:

```
bin/flink run -c  com.mycompany.app.App fkaf/target/fkaf-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I see the following runtime error:

```
Submitting job with JobID: f6e290ec7c28f66d527eaa5286c00f4d. Waiting for job completion.
Connected to JobManager at Actor[akka.tcp://flink@127.0.0.1:6123/user/jobmanager#-1679485245]
10/12/2016 15:10:06     Job execution switched to status RUNNING.
10/12/2016 15:10:06     Source: Custom Source(1/1) switched to SCHEDULED 
10/12/2016 15:10:06     Source: Custom Source(1/1) switched to DEPLOYING 
10/12/2016 15:10:06     Map -> Sink: Unnamed(1/1) switched to SCHEDULED 
10/12/2016 15:10:06     Map -> Sink: Unnamed(1/1) switched to DEPLOYING 
10/12/2016 15:10:06     Source: Custom Source(1/1) switched to RUNNING 
10/12/2016 15:10:06     Map -> Sink: Unnamed(1/1) switched to RUNNING 
10/12/2016 15:10:06     Map -> Sink: Unnamed(1/1) switched to CANCELED 
10/12/2016 15:10:06     Source: Custom Source(1/1) switched to FAILED 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.assign(Ljava/util/List;)V
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer09.open(FlinkKafkaConsumer09.java:282)
    at org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.util.FunctionUtils.openFunction(FunctionUtils.java:38)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractUdfStreamOperator.open(AbstractUdfStreamOperator.java:91)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.openAllOperators(StreamTask.java:376)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:256)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:584)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Any idea on why the method assign() is not being found? The method is there in the 
lib/kafka-clients-0.10.0.1.jar.

```
    ParameterTool parameterTool = ParameterTool.fromArgs(args);             

    DataStream<String> messageStream = env.addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer09<String>(parameterTool.getRequired("topic"), new SimpleStringSchema(), parameterTool.getProperties()));

    // print() will write the contents of the stream to the TaskManager's standard out stream
    // the rebelance call is causing a repartitioning of the data so that all machines
    // see the messages (for example in cases when "num kafka partitions" < "num flink operators"
    messageStream.rebalance().map(new MapFunction<String, String>() {       
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -6867736771747690202L; 

        @Override                                                           
        public String map(String value) throws Exception {                  
            return "Kafka and Flink says: " + value;                        
        }                                                                   
    }).print();                                                             

    env.execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

A `NoSuchMethodError` indicates a version mismatch.

I would guess the issue is that you try to connect a Kafka 0.9 consumer to a Kafka 0.10 instance. Flink 1.1.x does not provide a Kafka 0.10 consumer. However, a 0.10 consumer will be included in the upcoming 1.2.0 release.

You could try to build the Kafka 0.10 consumer yourself from the current master branch (1.2-SNAPSHOT) and use that one with Flink 1.1.2. The corresponding Flink APIs should be stable and backwards compatible from 1.2 to 1.1.

Comment: Thank you very much. That works. I have moved to Kafka 0.9 (instead of compiling consumer for 0.10). Now the process runs fine but it is not receiving any messages. I have a producer using rdkafka library and when I use "./rdkafka_consumer_example -g test -b localhost:33334 mytopic" it receives the messages the producer is producing. But the flink-kafka consumer is not receiving it when I run  "bin/flink run -c  com.mycompany.app.App fkaf/target/fkaf-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar --topic mytopic --bootstrap.servers localhost:33334". W

Comment: Any idea on what is causing the flink consumer to not receive it?

Comment: Just to clarify, I have removed the 'setProperty' as shown in the code above and started using parameterTool. rest of the code is same. What am I doing wrong that KafkaConsumer09 is not receiving the message? Appreciate any help. -- Thanks

Comment: How do you notice that no data is received? Your program does not include a sink to emit the data. If you add a `stream.print()` before `env.execute()` the data should be written into the TaskManager `.out` files in the `./log/` directory.

Comment: Thank you again. I did put stream.print(). Sorry for not stating that. Here is my complete program

Comment: Please see the original post, I have appended the complete program code at the end.

Comment: Just to add more information - I see that my messages are going to flink's output file directory and not my App's stdout (which is the terminal where I was running the command "bin/flink run -c com.mycompany.app.App fkaf/target/fkaf-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar --topic mytopic --bootstrap.servers localhost:33334". I was expecting them to be printed on my terminal